# Why doesn't setting MenuItem.InputGestureText cause the MenuItem to activate when I perform the input gesture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, key-bindings

I want to implement Keyboard shortcuts for a `MenuItem`. I have used the code below:

```
<MenuItem Header="_New" InputGestureText="CTRL+N" Click="NewMenu_Click">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source= "Images\NEW.PNG" Width="25" Height="28" />
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>`
```

But the `InputGestureText` property is not responding when I pressed the `CTRL+N`. I am using Visual Studio Express Edition 2010. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 11):

It is quite explicit in the documentation for the property:

> This property does not associate the
>   input gesture with the menu item; it
>   simply adds text to the menu item. The
>   application must handle the user's
>   input to carry out the action. For
>   information on how to associate a
>   command with a menu item, see
>   [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.command.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to make a `Command`, and associate the `InputGesture` with that command:

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand CreateNew = new RoutedCommand("New", typeof(Commands));

    static Commands()
    {
        SomeCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control));
    }
}

...

// Wherever you want to create the MenuItem. "local" should be the namespace that
// you delcared "Commands" in.
<MenuItem Header="_New" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.CreateNew}">

...

// Wherever you want to process the command. I am assuming you want to do it in your 
// main window, but you can do it anywhere in the route between your main window and 
// the menu item.
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.CreateNew}"> Executed="CreateNew_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

...

// In the code behind for your main window (or whichever file you put the above XAML in)
private void CreateNew(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

If you really just want a "New" command, you can skip creating the `RoutedCommand` and `InputGesture`, because that command is already created for you:

```
<MenuItem Header="_New" Command="New">

...

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="New" Executed="New_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

...

private void New_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution that doesn't involve commands and bindings is to override the owning Window's `OnKeyDown` method and search a menu item that has a `KeyGesture` that matches the keyboard event.

Here is the code for the Window's OnKeyDown override:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);

    // here I suppose the window's menu is named "MainMenu"
    MainMenu.RaiseMenuItemClickOnKeyGesture(e);
}
```

And here is the utility code that matches a menu item with the keyboard event:

```
    public static void RaiseMenuItemClickOnKeyGesture(this ItemsControl control, KeyEventArgs args) => RaiseMenuItemClickOnKeyGesture(control, args, true);
    public static void RaiseMenuItemClickOnKeyGesture(this ItemsControl control, KeyEventArgs args, bool throwOnError)
    {
        if (args == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));

        if (control == null)
            return;

        var kgc = new KeyGestureConverter();
        foreach (var item in control.Items.OfType<MenuItem>())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.InputGestureText))
            {
                KeyGesture gesture = null;
                if (throwOnError)
                {
                    gesture = kgc.ConvertFrom(item.InputGestureText) as KeyGesture;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        gesture = kgc.ConvertFrom(item.InputGestureText) as KeyGesture;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }

                if (gesture != null && gesture.Matches(null, args))
                {
                    item.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MenuItem.ClickEvent));
                    args.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            RaiseMenuItemClickOnKeyGesture(item, args, throwOnError);
            if (args.Handled)
                return;
        }
    }
```