# My key shortcut isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem

I am tryiong to add a shortcut to my menu Item but It doesn't seams to work.

here is my menu item:

```
<MenuItem Name="openMenuItem" Header="Open file" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Command="{Binding OpenFile}"></MenuItem>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

here is a picture of my menu:

[image]

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to work", does that mean you get an error message, an exception, a message in the VS output window, nothing?

Comment: No. It means that nothing is happening when i press ctrl + o but the menu works when I click with the mouse.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329292/why-doesnt-setting-menuitem-inputgesturetext-cause-the-menuitem-to-activate-whe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to the question you specifically asked:

> What am I doing wrong here?

I direct you to the [documentation for the `InputGestureText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext.aspx):

> This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item; it simply adds text to the menu item.

It's behaving as designed. `InputGestureText` just displays some text on the menu item; it does not change behavior, and in particular, it does not actually listen for that key gesture. This is somewhat unexpected, given that the corresponding property in WinForms *does* add behavior, but it's also called out by the `Text` suffix on the property name -- it's not the input gesture, it's just the text that's displayed to *tell* the user about the input gesture. It's set automatically when you use RoutedUICommand, but when you implement ICommand yourself, it's up to you to both set `InputGestureText` and listen for the key gesture.

What you're doing wrong is expecting this property to behave intuitively. You're far from the only one to be confused by this.

(The obvious follow-on question is "how do I add a keyboard shortcut for my MVVM command", but that's a separate question -- and one that's been asked and answered on StackOverflow multiple times; once you know that's the right question to be asking, you should be able to search for existing answers.)

Answer (score 2):

According to Nick at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d5536d93-b570-4e21-8668-641fa519cd95/ you need to add code to make it respond to the shortcut, like this:

```
public Window1()
{
  FilterCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control));
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Well in that example thay are using a RoutedCommand but I am binding to an ICommand. What will I do then?

Comment: Is there a way to add input gestures to an `ICommand`, for example the so called `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are predefined commands for Open and Close and other common ones. Take a look at  : [ApplicationCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx)

You would have something like :

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Width="75" />
  </Menu>
```